# Solidity Compilations: UnimplementedFeature

Tags: solidity

I am getting an Error in the IDE:

```
UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct ChatGroups.Message memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.
```

And I really don't know what to do with everything that I made ( It's commented in French )
There is the full code, and I really tried to find how can I implement what do I want with a different approach if someone could help for that and if I can preserv this code.

Thanks a lot for the people that are going to help !

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.12;

contract ChatGroups {
    struct Group {
        string name;
        address[] members;
        Message[] messages;
    }

    struct Message {
        uint id;
        string text;
        address author;
        bool deleted;
    }

    Group[] groups;

    address[] users;

    event GroupCreated(uint groupId, string groupName);

    event MessagePublished(uint groupId, uint messageId, string messageText, address messageAuthor);

    event MessageDeleted(uint groupId, uint messageId);

    event UserAddedToGroup(uint groupId, address user);

    event UserRemovedFromGroup(uint groupId, address user);

    function createGroup(string memory groupName) public {

        require(isUser(msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");


        groups.push(Group({
            name: groupName,
            members: new address[](1),
            messages: new Message[](0)
        }));
        groups[groups.length - 1].members[0] = msg.sender;


        emit GroupCreated(groups.length, groupName);
    }

    function publishMessage(uint groupId, string memory messageText) public {

        require(isUser(msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");


        Group storage group = groups[groupId - 1];


        require(isMember(group, msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");


        group.messages.push(Message({
            id: group.messages.length + 1,
            text: messageText,
            author: msg.sender,
            deleted: false
        }));


        emit MessagePublished(groupId, group.messages[group.messages.length - 1].id, messageText, msg.sender);
    }

    function deleteMessage(uint groupId, uint messageId) public {

        require(isUser(msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");


        Group storage group = groups[groupId - 1];


        require(isMember(group, msg.sender) && group.messages[messageId - 1].author == msg.sender, "Unauthorized user");


        group.messages[messageId - 1].deleted = true;


        emit MessageDeleted(groupId, messageId);
    }

    function removeUser(uint groupId, address user) public {

        require(isUser(msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");


        Group storage group = groups[groupId - 1];


        require(isAdmin(group, msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");


        require(isMember(group, user), "Unauthorized user");


        uint index = getMemberIndex(group, user);
        group.members[index] = group.members[group.members.length - 1];
        group.members.length--;


        emit UserRemovedFromGroup(groupId, user);
    }

    function addUser(uint groupId, address user) public {

        require(isUser(msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");


        Group storage group = groups[groupId - 1];
        require(isAdmin(group, msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");


        require(!isMember(group, user), "User already member of group");


        group.members.push(user);


        emit UserAddedToGroup(groupId, user);
    }

    function isUser(address user) private view returns (bool) {
        for (uint i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (users[i] == user) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function isMember(Group memory group, address user) public view returns (bool) {

        if (group.members[0] == user) {
            return true;
        }

        for (uint i = 1; i < group.members.length; i++) {
            if (group.members[i] == user) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function isAdmin(Group memory group, address user) public view returns (bool) {
        if (group.members[0] == user) {
            return true;
        }

        for (uint i = 1; i < group.members.length; i++) {
            if (group.members[i] == user) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function getMemberIndex(Group storage group, address user) private view returns (uint) {
        for (uint i = 0; i < group.members.length; i++) {
            if (group.members[i] == user) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return group.members.length;
    }
}
```

While compiling it, I'm getting this error, and I really have no solutions in my mind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your smart contract, there are some issues related to your logic in different operation. Thought, the main issue that you shared in this thread refers to a struct inside another struct (in this case, I say about `Message[]` struct).
The error say that you cannot pass a struct array initializing at runtime because this object is memorized inside storage space.

In details, you have to change the implementation for valorized attribute related to group struct (method: `createGroup(string memory groupName)`). The change to make is:

```
Group storage group = groups.push();
group.name = groupName;
group.members = new address[](1);
group.members[0] = msg.sender;
```

In this way, you create before a space into storage memory array, and then you fill it with the variable (if them has been valorized). At this point, you have to change the method called `publishMessage()` changing this line:

```
Group storage group = groups[groupId - 1];
```

with:

```
Group storage group = groups[groupId];
```

This same improvement you have to do in: `deleteMessage()` and `addUser()`.

In following lines, I put your smart contract with my changes:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.12;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract ChatGroups {
    struct Group {
        string name;
        address[] members;
        Message[] messages;
    }

    struct Message {
        uint id;
        string text;
        address author;
        bool deleted;
    }

    Group[] groups;

    address[] users;

    event GroupCreated(uint groupId, string groupName);

    event MessagePublished(uint groupId, uint messageId, string messageText, address messageAuthor);

    event MessageDeleted(uint groupId, uint messageId);

    event UserAddedToGroup(uint groupId, address user);

    event UserRemovedFromGroup(uint groupId, address user);

    function createGroup(string memory groupName) public {
        require(isUser(msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");

        // NOTE: I changed at this point your original implementation 
        Group storage group = groups.push();
        group.name = groupName;
        group.members = new address[](1);
        group.members[0] = msg.sender;
        emit GroupCreated(groups.length, groupName);
    }

    function publishMessage(uint groupId, string memory messageText) public {
        require(isUser(msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");

        Group storage group = groups[groupId];
        require(isMember(group, msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");
        group.messages.push(Message({
            id: group.messages.length + 1,
            text: messageText,
            author: msg.sender,
            deleted: false
        }));
        emit MessagePublished(groupId, group.messages[group.messages.length - 1].id, messageText, msg.sender);
    }

    function deleteMessage(uint groupId, uint messageId) public {

        require(isUser(msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");


        Group storage group = groups[groupId];


        require(isMember(group, msg.sender) && group.messages[messageId - 1].author == msg.sender, "Unauthorized user");


        group.messages[messageId - 1].deleted = true;


        emit MessageDeleted(groupId, messageId);
    }

    function removeUser(uint groupId, address user) public {

        require(isUser(msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");


        Group storage group = groups[groupId - 1];


        require(isAdmin(group, msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");


        require(isMember(group, user), "Unauthorized user");


        uint index = getMemberIndex(group, user);
        group.members[index] = group.members[group.members.length - 1];
        
        // NOTE: The attribute length() is only read-only, you cannot modify or handle the length of array using in this way! 
        group.members.length;


        emit UserRemovedFromGroup(groupId, user);
    }

    function addUser(uint groupId, address user) public {

        require(isUser(msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");


        Group storage group = groups[groupId];
        require(isAdmin(group, msg.sender), "Unauthorized user");


        require(!isMember(group, user), "User already member of group");


        group.members.push(user);


        emit UserAddedToGroup(groupId, user);
    }

    function isUser(address user) private view returns (bool) {
        for (uint i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (users[i] == user) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function isMember(Group memory group, address user) public view returns (bool) {

        if (group.members[0] == user) {
            return true;
        }

        for (uint i = 1; i < group.members.length; i++) {
            if (group.members[i] == user) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function isAdmin(Group memory group, address user) public view returns (bool) {
        if (group.members[0] == user) {
            return true;
        }

        for (uint i = 1; i < group.members.length; i++) {
            if (group.members[i] == user) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function getMemberIndex(Group storage group, address user) private view returns (uint) {
        for (uint i = 0; i < group.members.length; i++) {
            if (group.members[i] == user) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return group.members.length;
    }
}
```

P.S.: I think that you have to integrate users before call the various method inside users array. Although, the smart contract logic give you this error: "Unauthorized user". I think you should think better about this aspect